# Understanding Logistic Regressions model

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, logistic-regression

We check for risk factors for suicide attempts at teenagers

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

Now I have already checked statistically and found that all of the above give statically significant results. (The "Suicide_Trial" coulmn is the result column, the "y", not a risk factor).

specifically Live_Dormitory as it is positive - 1, raise the chance for suicide trial.
and as the teenagers ages, it also raises his chances for suicide.

yet the most significant factors were "divorced parents" and "psychiatric diagnosis" (With RR of up to 40)

To note, of course, i didnt show all the data and there are many examples where suicide trial is negative - namely, 0.
Also, i standardized the data before entering  to logistic regression model (with mean = 0 and Standard deviation = 1).

Now, the problem, when I build a logistic regression model on all the parameters and look at the coefficients, I see that Live_Dormity as well as "Age" are *Negative* coefficients namely, in the model i get, as the teenager ages and live at dormitory he has *Less* chances to attempt suicide.

But its not true from the statistical analysis i did before.

Moreover, when i run logistic regression only on age or live at dormitory i get the expected results and in those models, as the teenager ages and when he lives at dormitory, he really increases his chances for attempting suicide.

I understand that maybe there are connections between the variables and thats may explain but yet, if i insert to the model 2 different teenagers, that the only different between them is the age or dormitory, i get that the one with *lower* age and *not* living at dormitory has higher chances and it doesn't really makes sense to me.

Trying a simple Neural Network gave quite the same results.

Can I explain it another way? Maybe I miss something i dont understand? Why i get a non logical model? The explanation "there may be connection between the parameters" is really all it is about?

The code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scale = StandardScaler()
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx');  
X =df[['Age','Psychiatric_Diagnosis','Divorced_Parents','Live_Dormitory']]

scaledX = scale.fit_transform(X)

y = df['Suicide_Trial'];

logr = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
logr.fit(scaledX,y)

print("coef:",logr.coef_)
print("intercept:",logr.intercept_)
scaled = scale.transform([[15,0,0,1]])
print("scaled:",scaled)
scaled = scaled.reshape(4,1);

log_odds = np.dot(logr.coef_,scaled)  + logr.intercept_
odds = numpy.exp(log_odds)
probability = odds / (1 + odds)
print("prob:",probability)
```

Getting:

```
coef: [[-0.04272906  0.92784516  0.5705009  -0.70664492]]
intercept: [-4.98178798]
scaled: [[ 0.23573101 -0.23433062 -0.1545998   4.16648604]]
prob: [[0.00026336]]
```

As you can see the first and last coefficients are *Negative*

As for correlations, non of the parameters exceeds correlation of 0.6 between one another, therefore it doesnt seem that there is too strong correlation between the variables.

Here is the correlation matrix using pandas function corr:
[image]

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there is some collinearity among your variables (which you can check by plotting a correlation matrix & calculating VIFs).

Let's consider the following situation as an example. Imagine having `y` as an outcome variable, where `y` indicates whether or not a set of weights exceeds `5 kg` (or pounds, doesn't matter). Let's also introduce `x1` and `x2` as two predictors, where `x1` is the total number of weights, and `x2` is the number of small weights (where small is anything below some threshold).

If you build 2 individual models for `x1` and `x2`, you'll obviously obtain positive coefficients for both (the more weights, the more likely we'll exceed `5 kg`).

Now, if you put them all together in a single model, then the coefficient sign will change because if you increase the number of small weights while holding the total number of weights constant, the number of large weights will decrease so this will decrease the odds of exceeding `5 kg`.

In other words, the same variable can have different signs in different models, when combined with similar variables. And in your specific case, there's probably a strong correlation between `Age` and `Living in a Dorm`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to look at the correlations and added the correlation table to my question at the end, it doesnt seem that I have any parameter that is correlated with another with higher correlation than 0.6, namely the correlation between the variables doesnt seem too strong, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Anything >= 0.5 or <= -0.5 is considered a high correlation. Try removing some of the highly correlated variables or use PCA. Curious to know what happens if you only use Age & Live_Dorm (or Age & any other variable, as these pairs have a low correlation).

Comment: I tried to use only the pairs you advised, to know if the model is good, i calculated coefficient of determination - $R^2$, i get negative values, namely its bad for fitting with a linear model. Yet the values are less negative for as using all the variables at once. Im not sure what i should do, using a non linear model like Neural Networks, is not good as i want to represent relationship between the variables and write it on a paper, not sure what to do. If you have an idea i would like to hear.